# Inserting objects into Multiprocessing Manager,dict

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have the following code in `test.py`:

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
cache = manager.dict()

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

If I'm trying to insert objects into cache in another file e.g.

```
from test import *
cache[1] = 1 #this works
cache[2] = Test() #this fails/hangs
```

Why does the second case fail/hang? Is it possible to insert objects into a manager.dict()?

Edit: Hanging on Linux, but works on Windows. Python 3.7.3

Answer (score 0):

Update your manager.dict() with a normal dict.

```
tests = {}
test = test()
tests[test.name] = test
# insert other tests in the normal dictionary

obj = multiprocessing.Manager()
obj_tests = obj.dict()
obj_tests.update(tests)
```

Comment: I think that would work but I don't want to have a nested dict in this case

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Manager` needs to be `start`()ed first (or "entered" via `with`), i.e. the element setting code is waiting for a response from an associated server process, but never gets a response and hence hangs.  Under Linux anyway, and I stay away from Windows so wouldn't like to comment on that case.

The trivial fix for your posted code would be to do:

```
from test import manager, cache, Test
with manager:
    cache[1] = 1
    cache[2] = Test()
```

(use of `import *` is generally discouraged)

But I guess you probably want to do more than this, so a fix will be more involved.

Comment: nope still fails - you need to run the code on a unix env in python 3.7

Comment: oops, thought I tested the code I posted... obviously had a typo because it fails for me as well now, will try for a bit longer!

Comment: it's quite odd bc in Py 2.7 the code works on Unix but hangs in 3.7, not sure if that fact helps at all

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the fact that cache and Test are defined in the same file

Comment: I think it's more likely due to the `Manager` being created in one module and used in another

Comment: If I define Test in one file and define manager/cache in another file, import both of them and try cache[1] = Test() it works. Any idea why? Structuring it this way is not very ideal for my application

Comment: at a guess, `pickle`ing the object (or the reverse) it causes a new `Manager` to be created, which causes think to fail.  or might be due to fork causing Python to walk over itself, like e.g. https://codewithoutrules.com/2018/09/04/python-multiprocessing/